# Search through terminal history with up and down keys in OS X Lion

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, history

After I upgraded to OS X I am not able to use my ~/.inputrc bindings to search through the shell command history:

```
# these allow you to start typing a command and
# use the up/down arrow to auto complete from
# commands in your history
"\e[B": history-search-forward
"\e[A": history-search-backward
```

Any idea what I have to change or do? Are there any default keys for that I could use?

Comment: I don't know what could be wrong, but for comparison my .inputrc has the same bindings as yours and they work (Mac OS X Lion 10.7.1). In fact, if I remove my .inputrc altogether, the arrow keys still work, since by default they map to similar history commands, as shown by `bind -P`. What happens to the up/down arrow keys if you remove (or rename) your .inputrc file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The up/down history scrolling in Terminal only works in `bash`, not `sh`. Try typing `bash` in Terminal, and see whether the arrow keys work. If this is the case, you can go to preferences and set your default login shell to `/bin/bash`.

Answer (score 1):

For those who are looking for Page Up/ Page Down key instead of up/down arrow. Use the below settings.

```
# Page Up/Down
"\e[5~": history-search-backward
"\e[6~": history-search-forward
```

Tested with iterm and bash version 3.2

Answer (score 1):

For searching your history, you can also use a nifty feature of the bash shell.

This maybe a little off topic, but in bash shell you can use CTRL-R to search backwards in your shell history.

Example - search for ssh connections in your history:

```
tatooine-2257:~ mallert$
(reverse-i-search)`ssh': ssh mallert@localhost
```

And when I hit CTRL-R again, bash does a search within the former search results:

```
tatooine-2257:~ mallert$
(reverse-i-search)`ssh': ssh localhost
```

And you can hit CTRL-R again and again. You can also work with regular expressions.